# Linux server doesnt let change OID description - snmpset command

Tags: ubuntu, snmp

I got a Nagios. Need to get inbound traffic but for somehow the remote server has the same description for both NIC, and with snmpwalk doent recognize the interface name (eno1). Now i want to change the description of one of it interface but i cant do it. This is the command:

> snmpset -v 2c -c *community* *remote-ip* iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2.2 s "Intel
>   eno1"

The output:

> *Error in packet.
>   Reason: notWritable (That object does not support modification)
>   Failed object: iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2.2*

The snmpd.conf of remote server:

> group MyROGroup v1 xxxxxxx
>
> group MyRWGroup v2c xxxxxxx
>
> group MyROGroup usm xxxxxxx
>
> access MyROGroup "" any noauth exact all none none
>
> access MyRWGroup "" any noauth exact all all all

Remote Server info:

Description:    Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

How can i change this? I only need to find the way to difference between interfaces when I send a snmp request because both has "Intel Corporation I210 Gigabit Network Connection" as description, and the Nagios plugin doesnt let met send request by OID.

Thanks.

EDIT: Another problem with this server its that I cant send this kind of requests:

```
snmpwalk -v 2c -c community REMOTE-IP sysUpTime
```

Output:

```
sysUpTime: Unknown Object Identifier (Sub-id not found: (top) -> sysUpTime)
```

In the remote server I can execute mibs-download succefully, but I still getting this output when I send a snmpwalk. Maybe its related with the other problem.

Answer (score 1):

One solution could be to write a custom MIB file. This would allow you to map the destination OIDs to a human readable format defined locally.

Comment: I'm going to investigate about that. But I think there's another easier way to resolve this.